# Let $V,W$ vectorial spaces. Prove $(V \times W)^*$ is isomorphic to $V^* \times W^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Let $V,W$ vectorial spaces. Prove $(V \times W)^*$ is isomorphic to $V^* \times  W^*$

Note: $V^*,W^*$ is a dual space.

My work:

Let $T:(V\times W)^*\rightarrow V^*\times W^*$ defined by $T(f,g)=f(v)+g(w)$ with $v,w\in V,W$ and $f\in V^*$, $g\in W^*$

Is easy prove $T$ is lineal.

Go to prove T is injective.

Suppose $T(f,g)=0$ then, $f(v)+g(w)=0\forall v,w\in V,W$ 

This implies $f(v)=-g(w) \forall v,w\in V,W$

In particular for $w=0$ we have: $f(v)=-g(0)$

I'm stuck here. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to define on the other way: Let $v^{\ast},w^{\ast}\in V^{\ast}\times W^{\ast}$, define $\varphi(v^{\ast},w^{\ast})(v,w)=v^{\ast}(v)+w^{\ast}(w)$. Injectivity:  Suppose for any $(v,w)\in V\times W$, $\varphi(v^{\ast},w^{\ast})(v,w)=0$, then in particular, realize to $(v,0)$, then $v^{\ast}(v)=0$, this is true for any $v$, so $v^{\ast}=0$, similar to $w^{\ast}$. Surjectivity: For $u\in(V\times W)^{\ast}$, define $v^{\ast}=u(v,0)$ and $w^{\ast}(w)=u(0,w)$, then $\varphi(v^{\ast},w^{\ast})=u$.

Comment: Thanks, is a very clear proof. One question, i have a doubt with this. Because if $v^*(v)=w^*(0)$ then $w^*(0)=0$ Thanks!

Comment: No matter what, $w^{\ast}(0)=0$ is always true for linear functional. I mean, $w^{\ast}(0)=0$ does not follow by $v^{\ast}(v)=w^{\ast}(0)$ but the linearity.

Comment: Can be more explicit? Sorry for the inconvenience. I don't see why $v^*(v)=0$ D:

Comment: First of all, $w^{\ast}(0)=w^{\ast}(0\cdot 0)=0\cdot w^{\ast}(0)=0$. So if $v^{\ast}(v)+w^{\ast}(0)=0$, then $v^{\ast}(v)+0=0$, so $v^{\ast}(v)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, excellent! Sorry for all.